# iText 7 C# creating a pdf from a template and adding text to it

Tags: c#, itext7

I have a one page pdf template and need to create a new document with several pages. Each page needs to be as the first page of the template. Then i need to add text to each page. The pages are copied but the text is not added.

This is my code:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(stream));
PdfDocument cover = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(templatePath));

//First copy the pages
var totalPages=5;
var coverPage = cover.GetPage(1);
for (int i = 0; i < totalPages; i++)
{
  //If i do it to a blank page the text is visible
  //pdfDoc.AddNewPage();
  //I have tried both methods:
  pdfDoc.AddPage(coverPage.CopyTo(pdfDoc));
  //cover.CopyPagesTo(1, 1, pdfDoc);
}
                    
//Now i try to add text
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
var font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(fontPath);
for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
{
  //Edited
  Rectangle pagesize = pdfDoc.GetPage(i).GetPageSize();
  doc.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph("HEADER").SetFont(font).SetFontSize(22), pagesize.GetLeft(), pagesize.GetBottom(), i, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, 0);
  //doc.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph("HEADER").SetFont(font), 100, 700, i, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
 }
 doc.Close();
 cover.Close();
 pdfDoc.Close();
```

I have tried this options:

1. Canvas instead of document with no result (see code below)
2. If i use the AddNewPage() and not the cover page, then the text is added to the blank page (both document and canvas methods).
3. If i open and write directly to the template document the text is visible but the size is very small and position of the text is different compared to 2)

This is the canvas code inside the for instruction:

```
var canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.GetPage(i));
canvas.BeginText()
.SetFontAndSize(font, 22) //Edited
.MoveText(100, 700)
.ShowText("HEADER")
.EndText();
```

//UPDATED
Following the solution contributed by @mkl, i have changed the way i add the pages:

```
var coverPage = cover.GetPage(1);
Rectangle coverSize = coverPage.GetPageSize();
for (int i = 0; i < totalPaginas; i++)
{
    //Taken from this example: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-for-java/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents
    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.AddNewPage(PageSize.A4);
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.GetScaleInstance(
                        page.GetPageSize().GetWidth() / coverSize.GetWidth(),
                        page.GetPageSize().GetHeight() / coverSize.GetHeight());
    canvas.ConcatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
    var pageCopy = coverPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
    canvas.AddXObjectAt(pageCopy, 0, 0);
    //pdfDoc.AddNewPage();
    //pdfDoc.AddPage(coverPage.CopyTo(pdfDoc));
    //cover.CopyPagesTo(1, 1, pdfDoc);
}
```

Now i can see the text added, but the font size is much smaller than if instead of copying i do "pdfDoc.AddNewPage()", why is it? i would like it to be the correct font size.

Comment: You copy that original page and append to its content. That implies that any changes to the graphics state in that content (unless hidden by a save-graphics-state/restore-graphics-state envelope) affects your additions. For example, the current transformation matrix may change the user space coordinates in an unexpected manner, or the text rendering mode may be set to invisible. If you are not sure that that doesn't happen, you should wrap the existing content yourself. Alternatively import that page as form XObject and show that XObject on your page.

Comment: Concerning your *canvas code*: You don't set font or font size. Thus, some default is used at size 1!

Comment: @mkl, actually, `ShowText` throws an exception in this case: _iText.Kernel.PdfException: 'Font and size must be set before writing any text.'_

Comment: @rhens You're right... But that means, Tito, that you apparently forgot to mention that code...

Comment: Thanks, in my code i set the font ".SetFontAndSize(font, 22)" but i deleted that line to simplify, i didnt know it would throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in my tests. Maybe `(100,700)` is outside of the visual page area, which would typically be the case if your template page does not have its lower left corner at `(0,0)`.

This should put the text in the lower left corner:

```cs
Rectangle pagesize = pdfDoc.GetPage(i).GetPageSize();
doc.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph("HEADER"), pagesize.GetLeft(),
    pagesize.GetBottom(), i, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, 0);
```

If that works, you can work from the `pagesize` rectangle to calculate the appropriate position for the text.

Comment: Thanks but didnt work... i guess its about what @mkl says in his answer about the coordinates

Answer (score 0):

The solution to why the text dont appear is updated in my question at the bottom.
The reason why the coordinates dont match and the size is so small is the source template pdf that was exported with a very high px/inch for high level printing. Reducing it to 72ppp was the fix.